# How to get $form_id based on $form_state for custom form rule?

Tags: 7, rules, forms, entities

I'm building custom [form rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_forms) which is having `$form_state` as rule input parameter, however I would like to use [`drupal_form_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7) which requires `$form_id`.

Is it possible to fetch/compute automatically `$form_id` based on its `$form_state` to make my rule generic?

Or maybe there is some documentation that explains what `$form_state` should consist exactly?

My rule is like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_rules_action_info().
 */
function rules_forms_rules_action_info() {
  $actions['rules_forms_submit'] = array(
    'label' => t('Submit the form'),
    'group' => 'Rules Forms',
    'parameter' => array(
      'form_state' => array('type' => 'form_state', 'label' => t('Form state')),
    ),
    'base' => 'rules_forms_action_submit',
    'access callback' => 'rules_forms_integration_access',
  );
  return $actions;
}

/**     
 * Action: Submit the form.
 */
function rules_forms_action_submit($form_state) {
  // $form_id = ?
  drupal_form_submit($form_id, $form_state);
}
```

I've checked `$form_state` and it's a huge (~0,5MB size-like) [ArrayObject](http://php.net/ArrayObject) with the following main keys/properties:

```
build_info, temporary, programmed, programmed_bypass_access_check, cache, entityform, entityform_form_mode, field, storage, rebuild, rebuild_info, redirect, submitted, executed, method, groups, buttons, input, values, complete form, process_input, invalid_token, triggering_element, submit_handlers, clicked_button
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way was to pass `$form` ArrayObject which has `$form_id` present. So:

```
'form' => array('type' => 'form', 'label' => t('Form')),
```

needed to be added next to `$form_state` parameter in `hook_rules_action_info` and the final function looks like:

```
/**
 * Action: Submit the form.
 *
 * @param ArrayObject $form
 *   A reference to the form array of the form for which the event
 *   was triggered.
 * @param ArrayObject $form_state
 *   A reference to the form state array of the form for which the
 *   event was triggered.
 */
function rules_forms_action_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $form_id = $form['form_id']['#value'];
  $form_state = (array)$form_state;
  drupal_form_submit($form_id, $form_state);
}
```

For submitting entity form, check: [How to programatically submit an entityform?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/84929/1908)

Answer (score 0):

Given `$form_state` of an array or ArrayObject, the Form ID can be found in:

```
$form_state['build_info']['form_id']
```

or:

```
$form_state['build_info']['base_form_id']
```

as this location is used in Drupal core functions (e.g. [`drupal_prepare_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form/7)) so it should be pretty reliable.